# Unit Testing - Some difficulties mocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm working with some legacy code which I require to write some unit tests for. There is data access method with the following signature.

```
Task ExecuteReaderAsync(string procedureName, Parameters procedureParameters, 
    params Action<System.Data.IDataReader>[] actions);
```

which there is an implementation in the class i'm testing similar to this

```
private async Task<CustomObject> GetCustomObject(int id) 
{
    CustomObject obj = null;
    await db.ExecuteReaderAsync("nameOfProcedure", some parameters, 
    dr =>
    {
        obj = new CustomObject()
        {
            Prop1 = dr["Col1"],
            Prop2 = dr["Col2"]
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

What I'm struggling with is being able to control the values returned by `GetCustomObject`. If `ExecuteReaderAsync` actually returned something I could have a set up like this.

```
mockDataAccess.Setup(x => x.ExecuteReaderAsync("nameOfProcedure", It.IsAny<Parameters>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(new CustomeObject() { prop1 = "abc", prop2 = "def"};));
```

But the logic for specifying the values is an `Action<IDataReader>` which I don't control. I'm wondering if there are any tricks I could employ to do what I want, 
i.e. control the value of the object returned by `GetCustomObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following example

```
[TestClass]
public class LegacyCodeTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestExecuteReaderAsync() {
        //Arrange
        var mapping = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "Col1", "abc" },
            { "Col2", "def" }
        };

        var mockDataReader = new Mock<IDataReader>();
        mockDataReader
            .Setup(m => m[It.IsAny<string>()])
            .Returns<string>(col => mapping[col])
            .Verifiable();

        var mockDataAccess = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
        mockDataAccess
            .Setup(m => m.ExecuteReaderAsync("nameOfProcedure", It.IsAny<Parameters>(), It.IsAny<Action<System.Data.IDataReader>[]>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult<object>(null))
            .Callback((string s, Parameters p, Action<System.Data.IDataReader>[] a) => {

                if (a != null && a.Length > 0) {
                    a.ToList().ForEach(callback => callback(mockDataReader.Object));
                }

            })
            .Verifiable();


        var sut = new SUT(mockDataAccess.Object);

        //Act
        var actual = await sut.MUT(2);

        //Assert
        mockDataAccess.Verify();
        mockDataReader.Verify(m => m["Col1"]);
        mockDataReader.Verify(m => m["Col2"]);

        actual.Should()
            .NotBeNull()
            .And
            .Match<CustomObject>(c => c.Prop1 == mapping["Col1"] && c.Prop2 == mapping["Col2"]);

    }

    public interface IDataAccess {
        Task ExecuteReaderAsync(string procedureName, Parameters procedureParameters, params Action<System.Data.IDataReader>[] actions);
    }

    public class Parameters { }

    public class CustomObject {
        public object Prop1 { get; set; }
        public object Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SUT {
        IDataAccess db;

        public SUT(IDataAccess dataAccess) {
            this.db = dataAccess;
        }

        public async Task<CustomObject> MUT(int id) {
            var result = await GetCustomObject(id);
            return result;
        }

        private async Task<CustomObject> GetCustomObject(int id) {
            CustomObject obj = null;
            await db.ExecuteReaderAsync("nameOfProcedure", null,
            dr => {
                obj = new CustomObject() {
                    Prop1 = dr["Col1"],
                    Prop2 = dr["Col2"]
                };
            });
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Since you don't have control of the `Action<IDataReader>`, in this case the most that can be done is to make sure that the action does not fail. So that would mean passing an a mock reader that performs as expected for the action.

```
var mapping = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "Col1", "abc" },
    { "Col2", "def" }
};

var mockDataReader = new Mock<IDataReader>();
mockDataReader
    .Setup(m => m[It.IsAny<string>()])
    .Returns<string>(col => mapping[col])
    .Verifiable();
```

by using the call back to get access to the passed in parameters

```
.Callback((string s, Parameters p, Action<System.Data.IDataReader>[] a) => {

    if (a != null && a.Length > 0) {
        a.ToList().ForEach(callback => callback(mockDataReader.Object));
    }

})
```

the mocked reader can be passed to the actions called within the method under test.

This answer is tailored to the provided example in th OP so some modification may need to be made for it to apply to your specific scenario. This should be enough to get you going for situations like this.

Comment: Thank you very much, that does the job